# swift - uilalertcontroller textfield value returning empty

Tags: ios, swift, textfield, uialertcontroller

I have been staring at this for hours and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The following code keeps creating a new "Book" object, but the BookName is Blank...

Here is my code:

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Book", message: "What is the name of this Book?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) in
    textField.placeholder = "New Book Name"
    self.currentShelf.addNewBook(Book(bookName: textField.text))
}

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you lost the return from the closure in the addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler method, and I believe you have to make yourself the textfield delegate to receive the input.

Make sure class adopts the UITextFieldDelegate protocol:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, etc...
```

Then add the delegate line and add the missing Void return to the completion handler:

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Book", message: "What is the name of this Book?",  preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
  alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
  alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField: UITextField!) -> Void in
    textField.delegate = self
    textField.placeholder = "New Book Name"
    self.currentShelf.addNewBook(Book(bookName: textField.text))
})

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I also force unwrapped the textField as a UITextField! because I feel it is always safest in Swift if you can. It undermines the cleaner, less-decorated Swift syntax a bit, but I have found it ensures greater type safety. Looking over the couple times I have done this, I also ended the closure with `return` on the line before the `})` with no return value, but I think that was a legacy of the original Swift beta and it compiles fine without it.

Hope this helps!